# mongodb HMAC_Init_ex uses too much cpu

Tags: mongodb

I use a C driver to do an insert into mongodb, but the performance is not good, used perf top find that `HMAC_Init_ex` uses too much cpu time. How can I solve this problem?

I use the Authentication， mongodb uses crypto to encrypt all the info.

Comment: We'll need more details, what kind of performance are you expecting vs what you are getting, what OS/environment/configuration are you running in.

Comment: use perf top command   and find  HMAC_Init_ex  use most top cpu times like. samples  pcnt function 662.00 19.7% HMAC_Init_ex                                                                                                                               libcrypto.so.1.0.1e     268.00  8.0% _int_free                                                                                                                             /lib64/libc-2.12.so